# Remove some specific string with special character

Tags: c#, regex

**Input String**

```
string b = "14-03-002980 AND 14-03- [  ] (5)Description of 002981";
```

**In output String I Want Result As**

```
4-03-002980 AND 14-03-002981
```

I tried with below regex but it, not works

```
Regex.Replace(b, "[@&'(\\s)<>(5)Description of ]","");
```

Plaese, help me if anyone knows how to do this thing.

Comment: What is the rule here? What should be removed and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
\s+\[.*(?=\b\d+)
```

and replace it with empty string.

You start with one or more whitespace then match a `[` using `\[` and then `.*` consumes all the characters greedily and only stops when it sees a number using positive look ahead `(?=\b\d+)`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M8bf4c/1)**