# How to make a pattern using regex like below?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to make a pattern.

For example, my input is

```
string str = "15-16-00-014716 AND15- [  ] (5) Description of 16-00-014715";
```

Expected output is

```
15-16-00-014716 AND15-16-00-014715
```

I tried below regex:

```
Regex.Replace(YourString, @"\s+\[.*(?=\b\d+)","");
```

But the output is like

```
15-16-00-014716 AND15-0-014715
```

Comment: Try `(?s)\s+\[.*\n(?=\d)` pattern. What is the rule here, BTW? Why is your pattern like this? Maybe `\s+\[.*\n.*\n` or `\s+\[(?:.*\n){2}` is enough

Comment: Someone asked a similar question yesterday. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000369/remove-some-specific-string-with-special-character/56000405#56000405) Also for your current post, you can use this regex  [`(?s)\s+\[.*(?=\b\d+-\d+-)`](https://regex101.com/r/dcArSI/1) or [`(?s)\s+\[.*?(?=\b\d+-)`](https://regex101.com/r/dcArSI/2)

Comment: If you explain the rules, I think a better solution may be suggested. Why regex?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi

Actually, I want a single regex for below both strings As you provide a solution but it works on 2 number string, not 1 number.

1.  "14-03-002980 AND 14-03- [ ] (5)Description of 002981"
2.   "15-16-00-014716 AND15- [ ] (5)Description of 16-00-014715"

Comment: @DhavalPatel Ok, does `\s+\[(?:.*\n){2}` work for you? See [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b%5c%5b%28%3f%3a.*%5cn%29%7b2%7d&i=15-16-00-014716+AND15-+%5b++%5d+%285%29%0d%0aDescription+of+%0d%0a16-00-014715%0d%0a%0d%0a15-16-00-014716+AND15-+%5b++%5d+%285%29%0d%0aDescription+of+%0d%0a1600014715&r=). It removes a substring beginning with whitespaces, `[`, the rest of the line and the next line.

Comment: Sorry, Not Worked

Comment: @DhavalPatel Show your full relevant code. Add it to the question. As it is now, it is not reproducible as the input text is not a valid string literal, and it is not clear if there are any linebreaks in fact, or you just formatted it so for SO

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
void Main()
{
 
 string str="15-16-00-014716 AND15- [ ] (5) Description of 16-00-014715";
 string a= Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+\[(?:.*\n){2}","");
a.Dump();
}

Comment: @DhavalPatel: Can you add your samples in your post with expected vs current output? It is confusing whether you have newlines in your input string or not.

Comment: I think you need `Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+\[.*?(?=\b\d+(?:-|$))", "");`. See https://ideone.com/S7Emqu. So, it means you do not have any line breaks in the input.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi
void Main()
{
 String str="14-03-002980 AND 14-03- [ ] (5)Description of 002981";
 string str1="15-16-00-014716 AND15- [ ] (5) Description of 16-00-014715";
 string a= Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+\[(?:.*\n){2}","");

 a.Dump();
}

Expected out For Both String  like below

"14-03-002980 AND 14-03-002981"

"15-16-00-014716 AND15-16-00-014715"

Comment: See https://ideone.com/S7Emqu, I updated the demo

Comment: @DhavalPatel I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56021148/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+\[.*?(?=\b\d+(?:-|$))", "")
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/S7Emqu) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b%5c%5b.*%3f%28%3f%3d%5cb%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a-%7c%24%29%29&i=15-16-00-014716+AND15-+%5b+%5d+%285%29+Description+of+16-00-014715++++++%09%0d%0a15-16-00-014716+AND15-+%5b+%5d+%285%29+Description+of+1600014715&r=).

Regex graph:

[image]

Main points:

- `.*` should be non-greedy (`.*?` matches as few any chars as possible)
- `(?:-|$)` matches a `-` char or end of string position.

Comment: As OP didn't clearly specified the rules, you can simplify the regex to [`\s+\[.*?(?=\S+$)`](https://regex101.com/r/1mUtez/1)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Right you are, or (if whitespace is obligatory before the last numeric substring) `\s+\[.*\s(?=\S+$)`, that will be even faster.